# Cannot brew uninstall or unlink php in my mac

Tags: php, homebrew

I have this php currently running on my machine mac

```
PHP 7.3.9 (cli) (built: Nov  9 2019 08:08:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.9, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies`
```

But when I try to brew uninstall or unlink it simply appear the error like this

> Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.3

My reason is I want to install and use another version of php for example I want to use php@5.6

Comment: well, was it installed with brew in the first place ?  what does `which php` reveal ?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/php; that php version also can be found in this folder @YvesLeBorg

Comment: ok, thats the normal 'brew' path, what does ` ls -al /usr/local/bin/php`  (eg, is it a simlink, to where ?).  Also, what is your purpose to unlink this ? have you installed other versions, or planning to ?  Please add info to the question as you see fit, it may be more useful there to other SO users.

Comment: sounds like you want to first _re_install it, so that all the bindings get fixed (particularly: pay attention to any notices about commands you need to run to make sure all the bindings are correct, at the end of the install run). Then uninstall it.

Comment: I think this my php 7.3 was not in the same folder as other php version as it installed using other than brew because when I try to see ls -al /usr/local/bin/php it is link to php 7.4 but when I run php -v it is 7.3, its not in the same folder as other php, is there a way i can remove it or locate it from which folder it came from @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: as already suggested, `which php` should tell you every location PHP is found. If there's more than one version installed, it should list more than one location.

Comment: it came out like this /usr/bin/php @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: alternatively, make an info.php file, give it the content `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then run it. That'll give you basically all the information you need for deep dive digging (or, fire up that php, and run phpinfo() using the REPL)